# populate active choice from file in github

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I have a text file in Github with the following contents:

```
option1
option2
option3
```

I am trying to load the **Active Choice Parameter** with the following Groovy script:

```
def url = "curl https://PersonalAccessTokens@github.url/raw/Org/Repo/master/options.txt"
def proc = url.execute();
def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err);
data = outputStream.toString();
def list = data.readLines();
return list;
```

It is not working. Nothing is being returned in the list and I need help understanding why from the experts.

I am able to run the below code successfully in the Script Console:

```
def url = "curl https://PersonalAccessTokens@github.url/raw/Org/Repo/master/options.txt"
def proc = url.execute();
def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err);
data = outputStream.toString();
def list = data.readLines();
println(list);
```

and the following is returned:

```
[option1, option2, option3]
```

Does anyone have a clue what the issue may be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Low and behold it was just an issue with Script Approval.

Comment: where exactly is this code in your Active Choice script? having such a hard time getting anything but basic rudimentary groovy code to run